# app_Offline.htm doesn't work for subfolders of my application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have placed an app_Offline.htm in the root of my IIS7 application. This works for calls to pages on the root, but not for calls to pages in a subfolder of the application.

How comes? And how to make it work also for subfolders?

Comment: Are you subfolders defined as applications in IIS?

Comment: And I don't want them to convert to Applications.

Comment: Understood. And the requests for pages in the subfolders are requests that are being handled by ASP.Net? Not Html or other static pages?

Answer (score 1):

App_Offline.htm is not designed to work for subdirectories, only for the entire application, [Scott Gu on App_Offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx). I'm not sure how it works, but check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929494/how-does-app-offline-htm-stopping-an-iis-site-and-stopping-an-app-pool-affect-c) on that... To make this work for subdirectories you would need to implement custom logic in a handler that intercepts any requests for files where it is in the file path.