# i want app_offline.htm not working for a specific subdirectory

Tags: iis, web-config, app-offline.htm

I have a subdirectory in my application at iis 7.5. in the this subdirectory i put a web.config file which that redirect to other web application. when i put a app_offline.htm file in root of origin web app, this redirect not permitted. i want app_offline working for entire origin web app, but this subdirectory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803625/app-offline-htm-doesnt-work-for-subfolders-of-my-application-in-iis

Answer (score 2):

When using app_offline.htm it applies to the entire web application (root folder). IIS will not serve any other pages (.aspx) in the root or subdirectories so there is no way to transfer using response.redirect or server.transfer to another page. You could use a neta refresh but that would divert all requests to the other app, and defeat the purpose of app_offline.htm.

You may need to reconsider your design and separate your web apps.